# Face identification tool for Android or iOS

Tags: android, ios, face-recognition

I am trying to develop a mobile tool to check-in via face. This application is intended for employee place and time log-in. The app will simply take a picture or scan a face, look for a match in the database, and log-in the employee, then another employee will simply show his face to the camera to log-in for his/her shift.

I am looking for available face identification products, suitable libraries or any other suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: try open cv i hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda Labs Face API is what you need

http://api.lambdal.com/?ref=homepage

It's still in beta though. It's free for first 4000 detection and 1000 recognition per month :)

Answer (score 0):

On Android you could use the [FaceDetector class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) already available in the OS.
You can find an example [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html).